# Renaming a run command in github actions

Tags: devops, github-actions

Is it possible to rename the run command in github action?

For example for the given workflow file, I want to rename the 3rd run command that starts with `|`, to something which is a lot easier to understand.

```yaml
name: Lint, Build and Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x, 14.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: yarn install
      - run: yarn test
      - run: |
          chmod +x "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/scripts/upload_test_coverage.sh"
          "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/scripts/upload_test_coverage.sh"
```

For the above workflow file, the github actions UI is the following

[image: Github Actions UI]

Thank you.

Comment: You can add `name` to any step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify that step using the [`steps[*].name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsname) (the docs aren't very illuminating, though) property:

```yaml
      - name: Upload Test Coverage
        run: |
          chmod +x "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/scripts/upload_test_coverage.sh"
          "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/scripts/upload_test_coverage.sh"
```

It's the same property as the `steps[*].name` you have in your 2nd step for setting up Node.js.